# When can $M_c$ be described locally as a $C^1$ graph at every point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F(x,y) = x^2+2xy+3y^2$. For any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ let $M_c = F^{-1}(\{c\})$ be the level set at $c$. For which values of $c$ can $M_c$ be described locally as a $C^1$ graph at every point? 
I know that for $c>0$ the Implicit function theorem guarantees that I can write $M_c$ as either a function of $x$ or $y$ at every point. But at $c=0$ I see this doesn't hold. How about if $c<0$? I thought I could similarly apply the Implicit Function theorem but my textbook answer says that you cannot. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian matrix of your function is given by:
$$
J_f(x,y)= [2x + 2y , 2x + 6y]
$$
Any point in the domain such that $J_f(x,y) = 0$ is called **critical point**.  Any point in your codomain that is the image of a critical point is called a **critical value**.  The pre-image of a value $c$ will be a $C^1$ submanifold in the plane whenever $c$ is not a critical value.  The issue is that 0 is a critical value, as $J_f(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: So the preimage of $c<0$ actually is a $C^1$ graph?

Comment: @Garou To make sure I'm not being too coy in my above answer, the issue is that your function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}_+$.  It is in fact a convex function and it attains its global minimum uniquely at zero, at which it takes value 0.